# Voice Biometric in google assistance

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, biometrics, google-home

For one of project, to protect user PHI information we want to implement voice biometric solution in Google assistance app. Need your guidance in below:

1. Can we add voice biometric for the invocation phrase. I know, that google does voice match, but we want to implement voice biometric authentication, so that only authorized user can access specific skills. How we can do it, or access audio stream during invocation and control.
2. How we can get audio stream once the assistant app has been invoked. We want to add passive voice biometric in our Google Assistant app.

Please let me know if any details available. Thank you.
Note: Above information required  for  channel Google Home or Google Assistant device.

Answer (score 2):

For privacy and security reasons, at no point can you get access to the the voice stream or a recording of the users voice when using Actions on Google or through Google Home device.

If you were building your own device and using the Assistant SDK, you have access to the stream (since you have access to the hardware directly).

I'm not sure what you mean by "voice biometric" vs "voice match", but voice matching provides access to account linking so you can enforce access from only specific users.